# Unattended upgrades doesn't upgrade (or does nothing at all)

Tags: linux, debian, apt, upgrade

I've been trying to make the package *unattended-upgrades* running under Debian GNU/Linux (7.0) with no success so far.

The steps I have followed:

- Install *unattended-upgrades*
- Enable it

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
  ```
- Uncomment the following lines in */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades*

  ```
  "o=Debian,n=wheezy";
  "o=Debian,n=wheezy-updates";
  "o=Debian,n=wheezy-proposed-updates";
  "o=Debian,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security";
  ```
- Wait two days

It's supposed to run every day, but it did nothing by the time. I've checked its logs at */var/log/unattended-upgrades/* and apt history log at */var/log/apt/history.log* but nothing happened there since the installation.

Is there any step I am missing to enable it? After reading the doc under */usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README*, I think that the above are the only ones you have to follow to get it running.

Comment: What is the value of `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` (probably set in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`)?

Comment: In my case, it's set in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` and its value is **"1"**.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "o=Debian,a=testing";
        "o=Debian,a=stable";
        "o=Debian,a=stable-updates";
        "o=Debian,a=proposed-updates";
        "origin=Debian,archive=stable,label=Debian-Security";
};
```

The file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades must contain:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```